# How to type argument based on type of another argument?

Tags: typescript

How can one dynamically type `value` in `const set = (key: keyof Store, value: any)` to type(s) set in `Store` interface (for example: type `number` for key `foo` and type `string[]` for key `bar` ).

```js
import store from "electron-store"

interface Store {
  foo: number
  bar: string[]
}

const schema = {
  foo: {
    type: "number",
  },
  bar: {
    type: "array",
    items: {
      type: "string",
    },
  },
} as const

const config = new store<Store>({
  schema: schema,
})

const set = (key: keyof Store, value: any) => {
  return config.set(key, value)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping your style and implementing `set` a little more dynamic:

```
const set = <K extends keyof T, T = Store>(key: K, value: T[K]): void => {
  // ...
}

set('foo', 1);
set('bar', ['string']);
```

Or simply:

```
const set = <Key extends keyof Store>(key: Key, value: Store[Key]): void => {
  // 
}
```